# Breaking StreamingMarkupBuilder xml generation into smaller methods

Tags: xml, groovy, streaming

I have some code which generates xml for various jobs. It generates a lot of markup, so I use a StreamingMarkupBuilder. I am able to successfully generate the whole xml as one giant xml document. However, there are lots of repeated portions for the jobs, so I want to break it down into methods that will each generate some portion of the xml.  I tried calling methods but that simply placed the method names as xml tags in the output. Here is the document I am trying to generate. It has many more sections, but I removed them for the sake of brevity.

```
<jobs xmnlns:"https://www.monitoring.silver.star.com/mngs/v1/ngmon">
    <server>
      <detail>crcscanner1</detail>
      <ip> 220.10.12.72</ip>
      <state>active</state>
    </server>
 <job>
       <name>pcf-1</name>
       <stage>1</stage>
      <duration> 3 hours</duration>
      <submittedByprocess-ngm</submittedByProcess>
   <jobDetail>
       <printing>
       <card>10X6</card>
       <graphicSize>4X6</graphicSize>
       <scaleFactor> 1.5</scaleFactor>
       <material>paper<material>
     </printing>
   </jobDetail>
  </job>
   <job>
         <name>pcf-2</name>
         <stage>2</stage>
         <duration> 3 hours</duration>
         <submittedBy>-ngm</submittedBy>
     <jobDetail>
       <printing>
       <card>10X6</card>
       <graphicSize>4X6</graphicSize>
           <scaleFactor> 1.5</scaleFactor>
           <material>paper<material>
         </printing>
       </jobDetail>
   </job>
  ....
  </jobs>
```

I used this code to generate the xml which works fine. However, it will be very difficult to read when all the xml code is included as one giant xml code. I want to break it down into some where I passed the Server.java, Job.java classes to the methods. Here is the xml, or part of it as the document is huge.

```
 StreamingMakupBuilder builder = new StreamingMakupBuilder()
 markupBuilder.encoding = 'UTF-8'

        String orderXml = markupBuilder.bind {builder ->
           mkp.xmlDeclaration()
           jobs(xmlns:"https://www.monitoring.silver.star.com/mngs/v1/ngmon) {
               server{
                  detail('crcscanner1')
                  ip('220.10.12.72')
                  state('ACTIVE')
               }
               job{
                  name('pcf-1')
                  stage('1')
                  duration('3 hours')
                  submittedBy('ngm</submittedByProcess')

               }
          jobDetail{
             printing{
             card('10X6')
             graphicSize('4X10')
             scaleFactor('1.5')
             materia('paper')

         }
     buildJob(Job b) // This printed <buildJob></buildJob>
     ///... repeat the jobs
   }
```

}

I created this sample as a test since the original xml document is too big. However, it is based on trying to pass an object to the method.  This sample provided gives an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
    import groovy.xml.*

    def markupBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()

     ManKing mowgli = new ManKing()

       def xml = markupBuilder.bind { builder ->
          client {
              name 'mrhaki'
              buildAddress builder, 'Main St.', 42, 'Ducktown'
              buildManKing mowgli
          }
     }

def  buildAddress(StreamingMarkupBuilder builder, streetName, number, city) {
 builder.address {
  houseNumber number
  buildCity builder, city
 }
}

def buildCity( StreamingMarkupBuilder builder, city) {
 builder.city city
}

def buildManKing( StreamingMarkupBuilder builder, ManKing manKing){
  builder.manKing{
    name manKing.name
    jungleFriend manKing.jungleFriend
  }
}

class ManKing {
   String name
   String jungleFriend 
}
```

Here is the result of including that piece. You can see that the method name and object are used instead, so the solution suggested does not work for passing objects in the way the example does:

```
 Result:   


<client><name>mrhaki</name><buildAddress>Ducktown</buildAddress>

      <buildManKing>ManKing@3eee45b2</buildManKing></client>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution where I am able to pass the whole object and call a set of methods. I used a delegate, to get the scope of the closures in the createJobXml method where the xml is built.

def createJobXml(JobInfo jobInfo){
   {

```
StreamingMarkupBuilder builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
buildJob.delegate =delegate
buildServer.delegate =delegate
builder.bind{
          jobs{
             buildServer(jobInfo.server)
             buildJob(jobInfo.job)
          }
   }
}

def buildJob = { Job j ->
  job {
     etc.
  }

}

 def buildServer = { Server s ->
   server {
     etc.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to break your XML creation up, by using separate methods for each data type.

```
def markupBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def xml = markupBuilder.bind { builder ->
 client {
  name 'mrhaki'
  buildAddress builder, 'Main St.', 42, 'Ducktown'
 }
}

def buildAddress(builder, streetName, number, city) {
 builder.address {
  houseNumber number
  buildCity builder, city
 }
}

def buildCity(builder, city) {
 builder.city city
}
```

The methods can be of course scattered across several classes.

The full example and explanations are [at groovy-goodness](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/04/groovy-goodness-refactor-xml-creation.html)

Comment: I would have to pass 12 fields this way.  I want to be able to pass an object. I tried that approach and my method names were used in the xml instead. I can't have a method like buildJob a, b, c , d , e ,f g, h, . On the other hand If I pass 2 few arguments , then Ill have too many methods. The xml is only showing a few parts, there is a lot more.

Comment: It created the tag, <buildJob>com.ngmonitor.alljobs.Job@a..</buildJob>

Comment: I appreciate your attempt but your solution does not work for me.